# Laying out JPanels to make a simple GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt, jpanel

first of all, this is more or less my first GUI and ive learned Java for not more then a week, so it might contain some serious programming errors.

What i have right now is: 
Buttons and labels are part of OptionPanel and are on the left, DrawingPanel is about 5x5 px in size and is on the right.

What I am trying to do is a simple test, to get me more familiar with the GUI. The rectangle should be movable and re-sizeable by the user when clicking the respective buttons:
http://www.upload.ee/image/612005/JFrame2.jpg

Right now i have:

JFrame MainFrame - Makes JFrame (Not using the setSize function. using .pack() instead. not sure about it)

JPanel MergedPanel - FlowLayout - Adds JPanel OptionsPanel and JPanel DrawingPanel together and gets injected to JFrame MainFrame

JPanel DrawPanel - This JPanel is responsible of drawing the rectangle.
JPanel OptionPanel - FlowLayout - This JPanel is responsible of the buttons.

Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never call `setSize()` in your code. In Java, you use [layout managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to do the layout (read that tutorial).

Subclassing `JPanel` to implement different parts of which the UI is composed is a good practice, but should not be overdone (it's fine to have an UI class that adds 3 other plain `JPanel` instances to itself for layout purposes).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MiG Layout](http://miglayout.com/) : one can make pretty easily java layouts with that.